# Разные формы регистрации для разных ролей в Drupal 8?

Tags: php, drupal

Добрый день. Есть сайт на drupal 8, в котором существуют несколько ролей для авторизованных пользователей. При регистрации необходимо указывать разные данные для разных ролей. Поэтому вопрос - как сделать для каждой роли свою форму регистрации?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: @E_p Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Answer (score 0):

Существует модуль для решения сей проблемы http://dgo.to/profile.
Настраиваете тип профиля, поля для него, связываете его с ролью.